# How can I change the Flask-SQLAlchemy URI after a certain period of time?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, rds

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy to connect to a Postgres database on AWS RDS. The password to connect to the database expires every 15 minutes, after which I need to generate a new one for new connections to the database (open connections are fine).

I can't figure out how to configure Flask-SQLAlchemy to use a function to generate the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` configuration parameter. All the documentation and discussion around this points at using a static value set at startup.

I know how to do this using regular SQLAlchemy with scoped sessions, etc. But I was really hoping for a solution using Flask-SQLALchemy.

Comment: did you try to use [Custom Connection Function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html?highlight=reconnect#using-a-custom-connection-function) or [engine_connect listen](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html?highlight=reconnect#custom-legacy-pessimistic-ping)? Looks like what you need.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, yeah, I think a Custom Connection Function will work, although only with the Flask-SQLAlchemy release as of two days ago, which is very fortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness' sake, I got this working using a [custom connection function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html?highlight=reconnect#using-a-custom-connection-function) like @DanilaGanchar suggested.

To configure this in Flask-SQLAlchemy, you need to use v2.4.0 or greater (which was incidentally only [released the day before I asked this question](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/changelog/#version-2-4-0)). That version has a [`SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/) config, which allows passing in a dictionary of kwargs for SQLAlchemy's `create_engine` function.

One important note is that Flask-SQLAlchemy still expects a value for `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, even if your `creator` function is handling creating the connection anyway.

So the full solution looks like

```
# config.py

def _get_conection():
    # Get all your connection information
    return psycopg2.connect(host=host, port=5432, password=password, ...

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql+pyscopg2://"
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"creator": _get_connection}
# More settings etc.
```

```
# app.py

from app import config
from app.db import db

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config_from_object(config)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

Comment: `{"creator": _get_connection()}` should be `{"creator": _get_connection}`